Boat floatation load
I was reading about boats, from what i was reading a qubic meter of air should be able to float a 1 ton boat
so as far as i understand the equalibrium point will be if a boat wight is 1 ton - 1 qubic meter of air will be below the water line
On the other hand i saw a lot of boats that contain much less air and floats, for example this one:

In the picture there are more then 20 people on board + the wight of the boat itself would be about 1 ton although the two floats it is mounted on are about 180L each and are half way submerged
How could that be ? i would expect 3 times that volum to be fully submerged

are you sure about the volume of the floats?

Based on the displaced volume of water you gave, the buoyancy in pound-force (weight of the volume of water displaced) is about 400 lbf. That is obviously insufficient to float the boat in the picture. The  volume is obviously incorrect.
Based on the photo, I would estimate the length of each tube to be about 15 ft, with a diameter of about 1.5 ft. Based on 50% submersion, that's a displaced volume of one tube or about 26.5 ft$^3$ which, at 62.4 lb/ft$^3$,is a buoyant force of about 1700 lbf.  Whether or not that's adequate would depend on the maximum passenger and equipment load rating of the vessel in terms of number of passengers and total weight.
Hope this helps.
